# When dragging image from one contentEditable DIV and dropping it to another one in Firefox, image completely disappears

Tags: javascript, html

When I'm trying to drag an image from one contentEditable DIV and drop it to another one in Firefox, image completely disappears.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/VvAT2/1/

In both IE and Chrome image is moved (as expected), but in FF it's just removed from the first one, and doesn't appear in the second one. To me it seems weird especially since there is no javascript at all here, so it's kind of default browser's behavior. Is there any good way to control it? (I'd prefer not to implement the whole DD-thing in javascript, it obviously shouldn't be necessary for such trivial case).

PS: When it comes to dragging images from outside of the contentEditable, everything seems to be the same for all three browsers - image is just copied, and that's fine...